# how to record user interactions globally in vb?

Tags: api, vb6

I have an application that needs to record users interactions globally. I mean mouse clicks,scroll,keyboard keys, ... . My Applications is in visual basic and I have tried using apis, but had no success. I wanna know which API should I use for this reason.

Thanks in advance for any help form your side.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of APIs that do "CBT hooking".  Google it, and you will find a lot of information.  In particular, have a look at the [SetWindowsHookEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), which lists all the activities you can capture this way.